# How to refresh the ViewModel to update the View

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, mvvm

I have implemented a refresh application bar button in my MainPage, and I would like to use this button's click event to reload the view model. I am not sure of how to accomplish this, however. When my view is first loaded, the view model is called in the xaml like so:

```
DataContext="{Binding InformationProvider, Source={StaticResource DeviceInformationViewModel}}"
```

where my view model is

```
public class DeviceInformationViewModel
{
    private static IInformationProvider informationProvider;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the device information to display.
    /// </summary>
    public IInformationProvider InformationProvider
    {
        get
        {
            if (informationProvider == null)
            {
                if (DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
                {
                    informationProvider = new FakeInformation();
                }
                else
                {
                    informationProvider = new RealInformation();
                }
            }

            return informationProvider;
        }
    }
}
```

`InformationProvider` essentially just gets device information from the model. This is performed once when the application is loaded, although I would also like to perform this on the refresh button click event as well. How might I accomplish this in the code behind of my MainPage? Also, is this the correct approach? If not, how might I go about accomplishing this solution?

Answer (score 2):

The bindings to your view model won't update unless they know to do so.  The typical method of doing this is to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your view model and then call `NotifyPropertyChanged` when the properties on your view model are changed.  In you case you could simply implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then call the `NotifyPropertyChanged` method for every property in your refresh button.